# Do not traverse directories using the WinSCP .NET assembly

Tags: winscp, winscp-net

I am trying to upload the contents of a folder (but not the sub-folders, which have backup files, archive files and errored files) to a server using the [WinSCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinSCP) .NET assembly. Is this even possible? If so, how do I do it?

Quick code clip of my existing piece:

```csharp
// string mode ...
// Session sess ...
// TransferOperationResult res ...

TransferOptions tOpts = new TransferOptions();
tOpts.FileMask = c.SearchPattern;
tOpts.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary;
tOpts.PreserveTimestamp = true;

SetMessage("Uploading files");
res = sess.PutFiles(Path.Combine(c.LocalPath, c.SearchPattern),
                    c.RemotePath, 
                    c.DeleteAfterXFer, 
                    tOpts);
```

Is there some way of saying something to the effect of:

```csharp
tOpts.TopDirectoryOnly = true
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [file mask `|*/` to exclude all (sub-)directories](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask#directory).

Use the [`TransferOptions.FileMask` property](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_transferoptions#filemask) to set the file mask.

```csharp
TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
transferOptions.FileMask = "|*/";

session.PutFiles(@"d:\toupload\*", "/home/user/", false, transferOptions).Check();
```

Specifically for your sample, do:

```csharp
tOpts.FileMask = c.SearchPattern + "|*/";
```

---

Also documented in WinSCP FAQ [How do I transfer (or synchronize) directory non-recursively?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_script_non_recursive)